# Cannot upload to s3 bucket with public access blocked

Tags: amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload to an s3 bucket which works fine if I set Block all public access: Off. However, with it on and the following bucket policy I get an access denied message

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1594969692377",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1594969687722",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::066788420637:user/transloadit2"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname"
        }
    ]
}
```

I thought that enabling/disabling public access just allowed rules to be created to then make the bucket public? I don't understand why it is blocking my upload when it is disabled.

Many thanks,
Matt

Comment: How are you performing the upload? What commands and credentials are you using?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein thanks for the suggestion. It was actually an issue with the upload as the objects were being set as public but with public access denied this was failing

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you wish to grant permission for a specific IAM User to upload to an Amazon S3 bucket.

For this, instead of creating a bucket policy you should **add a policy to the IAM User themselves**, such as:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**Note:** This policy is granting **too many permissions**, including permission to delete the bucket and all its contents. I recommend that you limit it to the specific API calls desired (eg `PutObject`, `GetObject`).

Basically:

- If you wish to grant access to one user, put the policy on the IAM User
- If you wish to grant access to 'everybody', use a bucket policy

Permissions granted to the IAM User are not impacted by *S3 Block Public Access*.

Answer (score 0):

You use the bucket itself as a resource. If you want to do operations over objects (put, get etc.), you need to put objects path to the resource. So, in your case, you should update your policy like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1594969692377",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1594969687722",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::066788420637:user/transloadit2"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```